# How can I shatter a model and have it reassemble in a different shape?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I'd like to have a model shatter and then have the fragments float about a bit, then reassemble into a different model. How would I do this?

I know of cell fracture, but I don't know what all of the variables and settings do when fracturing something. I know enough about physics simulations to make a model explode.

I'd like the pieces of the shattered model to be
[this kind of shape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OX3cm2qNSqE).

The fragments are all pointing in the same direction and long and thin.
How would I achieve this/is it possible/is it possible for a novice user to do without a lot of confusion?

Thanks

Comment: One thing to try are keyed particle systems, [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPCs4XbGth8). *"for a novice user to do without a lot of confusion..."* I don't think so. Some practice is going to be required

Comment: watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do0jF3zb5_U

Answer (score 2):

One tactic that might be useful is to have the two models both be shattered, but the second one in reverse.  In the time between slowly replace the pieces of the first model with the pieces of the second (which will be hard to notice in all the confusion).  So the first model shatters; over time its pieces are replaced by pieces of a second model; which then unshatters.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer for now: Use Sverchok Add-On Voronoi node, this kind of long shredded shattering should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting two objects and using Quick Explode. There should be an option to morph the two objects. (This uses keyed particle systems behind the scenes, but takes care of the setup work.)